# Efficiently selecting random duplicate entries in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
   id   date
  250  01-JAN-15
  250  01-MAR-15
  360  01-JUN-15
  470  01-FEB-15
  470  01-DEC-15
  470  01-NOV-15
  780  01-APR-15
  790  01-SEP-15
  790  01-MAY-15
```

I want to **randomly** select rows such that duplicated `id`s will appear only once. For example:

```
   id   date
  250  01-MAR-15
  360  01-JUN-15
  470  01-FEB-15
  780  01-APR-15
  790  01-SEP-15
```

My current solution uses an analytic function, which takes a long time to run on hundreds of millions of rows:

```
select * from(
 select aa.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by dbms_random.value) as random_flag 
 from table aa)
where random_flag = 1
```

Any tips on how to get the same result without analytic functions?

Comment: Can u take min() or Max() value in the group instead of random ?

Comment: nope. It has to be random

Comment: Do you want to set all `ID`s or just a subset?

Comment: I need all `ID`s

Comment: What you are doing currently seems like the most efficient way already. What are you using this for though? Perhaps the idea of picking a random row for each distinct ID is not the only (or perhaps not even the best) way to solve your higher-level problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is used to prepare data for a machine learning task, but the high-level problem is out of scope for this question. I asked the question because my experience tells me that you should avoid analytics function if you can.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT id, (select t2.date from table t2 where t2.id = t1.id and rownum = 1)
FROM table t1
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: How does **random** fit into this solution? ROWNUM is not guaranteed without a specific ordering clause, but that doesn't make it random.

Comment: the order in which the records are retrieved by Oracle is not fixed. Hence we cannot predict the outcome of the query. Rownum is just used to restrict the number of records to be fetched, in this case to be 1.